# Doctrine 2 base entities like those in doctrine 1?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm starting a new project with Symfony2/Doctrine2 and I generated my entities from the DB with the mapping:convert and mapping:import commands.

My entities are fine, but I only have the generated entities. Back in Doctrine1/Symfony1, you had your entities generated twice : once in the doctrine folder, an almost empty class just extending the second one in doctrine/base folder where all the doctrine internals were (getters/setters, fields...)
This way, you could add your own methods in the first file where they remained untouched even if you generated again the entities (only the doctrine/base files were modified by the generator).

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the generate command only generates getters and setters that are undefined and appends them to the (entity) file. This means that your custom getters/setters will never be overwritten. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly : If I remove a row from a table and use again the mapping:convert and mapping:import, what will happen to the generated class file ? Will it be entirely rewritten (even the methods that I wrote) ? Also, the "two files per entity" system of doctrine1 helped to keep things clean and tidy with one file that kept only the code you had written and the other all the code doctrine had generated.

Comment: The mapping command is intended to be run only once: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html.  In most cases you will edit your entities then use doctrine:schema:update to sync the database tables.  It may sound like a step back but it means that no bases classes are required.

Comment: I've played a bit with the three commands at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html and the schema:update command.It's indeed a bit of a step back. When you mapping:import to a yml file and then change a column's name in the yml file, generate:entities modifies the entity class, leaving the old column there as simple string variable and adds the new column declaration and getters at the end of the file, leaving my own methods in the file... Doctrine 2 has some good ideas, but sadly this part is less efficient than before. Thanks for the clarifications though.